# Boost asio tcp threaded. Wait for new sample?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have an application that sends a struct as serialized data using boost asio.

This all works well,  but I think I am running it inefficiently. 
The actual data that i am sending is only updated every 30ms or so, but on both the send and receive functions, i am running a loop that takes less than 1ms.

This means that i am sending the same data multiple times.

My question is:

How can i make this approach more efficient?

I can easily add a condition_wait in the send function to wait for a new sample, but is it possible to make the receive side wait for a new *sent* sample?

The send function is:

```
    void Connection()
    {
        static auto const flags = boost::archive::no_header | boost::archive::no_tracking;

        while(true)
        {
            boost::asio::io_service ios;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint
                = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;


            // program stops here until client connects.
            acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());

            connected = true;
            // Send 
            while (connected == true)
            {               
                    try
                    {
                        stream.flush();

                        boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(stream);
                        archive << data_out; //data_out is my struct, serialized. It is updated and filled in a mutex every 30ms or so.

                    }
                    catch (...) {
                        std::cout << "connection lost, reconnecting..." << std::endl;
                        connected = false;
                    }

                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));


            }
        }
    }
}
```

The receive function on the other end is:

```
void Connect()
{

    while (true)
    {
        do {        
            stream.clear();
            stream.connect("127.0.0.1", "4444");

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        } while (!stream);

        bConnected = true;

        while (bConnected == true && ShutdownRequested == false)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.flush();
                boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(stream);
                archive >> data_in; //to a struct

         }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little program to read data from a socket as fast as possible

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 3001));

    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);

    for (;;)
    {
        char mybuffer[1256];
        int len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mybuffer,1256));
        mybuffer[len] = '\0';
        std::cout << mybuffer;

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it using the `iostream` class, but using the `socket` class instead you simply call `receive` or `read` to block until bytes are detected on the network (or the `async_*` variants of those calls if you don't want to block).

If your data structure is of fixed length, you can simply call `read` with your structure size as the expected number of bytes to receive. If it's of variable length, theres a bit more handling to do. You could add the expected size as the first few bytes in your payload and call `receive` in a loop until that number of bytes is received.

There are good examples in the boost documentation if you haven't checked them yet. I'd recommend looking at the [Chat](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.chat) and [Echo](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.echo) examples.